# Can linux kernel keyboard interrupt be interrupted by further keyboard interrupt

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling, keyboardinterrupt

In linux 0.11 kernel, the keyboard interrupt handler is a **trap gate**, i.e. does not disable interrupt from INTR pin,

```
_keyboard_interrupt:
push eax
...
in al,60h // read scan code
call key_table[eax*4]
reset keyboard
...
mov al, 20h
out 20h, al // send EOI to 8259A interrupt controller
call _do_tty_interrupt
...
pop eax
iretd
```

While CPU is processing in **_do_tty_interrupt** after **sending EOI to 8259A interrupt controller**, another keyboard interrupt may be asserted. **Can keyboard interrupt be interrupted (nested) by further keyboard interrupt?**

Answer (score 0):

They keyboard has a buffer in it, failure to read the key from the buffer will prevent any subsequent IRQs from the keyboard, there is no need to disable the interrupt.

If another interrupt occurs during `_do_tty_interrupt` the PIC tells the CPU about it and a new interrupt handler is executed once the CPU saves state information on the stack again.

Comment: You might want to consider adding an explanation of the interrupt handshake between the keyboard controller and the 8259A.

Comment: Before sending EOI to 8259A interrupt controller, **the key has been read from the key buffer and then the keyboard is reset** (see my updated question), so I think subsequent IRQs may be generated from the keyboard. Is it right?